# Spring Integration SFTP Delete Remote File On Demand

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I am trying to delete a single file from the remote SFTP bucket when a certain thing happens in my app (we save the file to blob storage).  I have not been able to do this. All that I have been able to see how to do is to always delete a file via and outbound channel adapter after processing is done.  I am using the Java configuration.

Here is my code:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpDeleteChannel")
public MessageHandler deleteHandler(SftpInboundProperties properties) {
    SftpOutboundGateway SFTP = new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(properties), "rm", "'" + properties.getRemoteDirectory() + "'");
    return SFTP;
}

@Gateway(requestChannel = "sftpDeleteChannel")
    Boolean delete(Message<File> file);
```

This is the service activator that facilitates the entering of the file:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handler(FileProcessingService fileProcessingService) {
    return message -> {
        fileProcessingService.processFile((Message<File> message);
    };
}
```

I am getting this error message:

> Reply message received but the receiving thread has exited due to an exception while sending the request message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [bean 'deleteHandler'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/.../SftpInboundConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@6ff37443']; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to remove file.; nested exception is 3: Permission denied, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=/REMOTE_FILE_PATH/COMPLETE_FILE_NAME, headers={file_remoteHostPort=127.0.0.1:2222, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@34d7c35d, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@34d7c35d, file_name=COMPLETE_FILE_NAME, file_remoteDirectory=//sftp_remote, file_originalFile=/REMOTE_FILE_PATH/COMPLETE_FILE_NAME, id=2252eee1-6086-c9d9-c421-403f8a0bfc28, file_relativePath=COMPLETE_FILE_NAME, file_remoteFile=COMPLETE_FILE_NAME, timestamp=1588177024991}], headers={id=0d2b19ca-0e7c-7ba8-58cf-f225c126048c, timestamp=1588177025001}] for original GenericMessage [payload=/REMOTE_FILE_PATH/COMPLETE_FILE_NAME, headers={file_remoteHostPort=127.0.0.1:2222, file_name=COMPLETE_FILE_NAME, file_remoteDirectory=//sftp_remote, file_originalFile=/REMOTE_FILE_PATH/COMPLETE_FILE_NAME, id=9f29dd04-362a-ae93-df97-b392572d8864, file_relativePath=COMPLETE_FILE_NAME, file_remoteFile=COMPLETE_FILE_NAME, timestamp=1588177023713}]

I'm not sure if I'm doing things incorrectly or if outbound gateways are not for specific, on-demand deletes, or both.  Would love some help.

Thanks!

Edit:

I am able to delete files on the server using SftpInboundFileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true), so as far as the sftp bucket is concerned, I can delete files.  Do I need to change something in my InboundChannelAdapter? Here it is below:

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "sftpChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "${com.esrx.dhf.listener.sftp.inbound.poll-interval:5000}"))
    public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource(SftpInboundProperties properties, JdbcMetadataStore metadataStore) {
        SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
                sftpInboundFileSynchronizer(properties, metadataStore));
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + "sftp_local"));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setMaxFetchSize(1);
        source.setLocalFilter(new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore, SFTP_LOCAL_PERSISTENT_PREFIX));
        return source;
    }
```

EDIT: SOLVED

So the venerable Gary Russel's real answer was that I should specify the full path of the file in the SftpOutboundGateway.  So now the working solution means the new OutboundGateway looks like this:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpDeleteChannel")
public MessageHandler deleteHandler(SftpInboundProperties properties) {
    return new SftpOutboundGateway(
            sftpSessionFactory(properties),
            "rm", 
            "'" + properties.getRemoteDirectory() + "/'" + " + " + "headers['file_remoteFile']");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is correct.

See the cause:

> nested exception is 3: Permission denied,

You don't have permission to delete the file.

Comment: If that is true, what I am missing? When I automatically delete files after they are read in using setDeleteRemoteFiles, it works like a charm.  Do I need to change something on the incoming file or InboundChannelAdapter?

Comment: After further review, it looks like you are trying to remove the directory `"'" + properties.getRemoteDirectory() + "'"`. From the content of your error, it looks like you need `payload` in that expression. Although it looks like that's a `File` object; you need to construct the file name using the remote directory name + "/" + the remote file name. So `"'" + properties.getRemoteDirectory() + "'/'" + "headers['file_remoteFile']"`

Comment: I am having trouble getting the syntax of the expression correct.  Should that look like "'/sftp_remote'/'headers['file_remoteFile']" when evaluated? When its like that, it complains that the statement isn't finished. When I add another ', it says there is more the expression but it's done evaluation.   I am playing around with it.

Comment: `file_remoteFile=COMPLETE_FILE_NAME, timestamp=1588177024991 - it's an SftpFileInfo; so... `"'/sftp_remote/' + headers['file_remoteFile'].filename"` . Or you can use `headers['file_relativePath']` which is just the name.

Comment: Got it, thanks, The winning combination was: "'" + properties.getRemoteDirectory() + "/'" + " + " + "headers['file_remoteFile']".

Comment: Sorry; I was just winging it - I should have tested but I was busy. Glad you sorted it.